# Equivalent Programmatic code to int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter and int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

Hi Can any one help me in getting the equivalent programmatic code for below spring context configuration .

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${availableServerPort}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${userid}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
            channel="ftpChannel"
            session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
            filename-pattern="*.txt"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            remote-directory="/"
            local-directory="#{ T(org.springframework.integration.samples.ftp.TestSuite).LOCAL_FTP_TEMP_DIR}/ftpInbound">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter  id="ftpOutbound"
                channel="ftpChannel"
                remote-directory="/"
                session-factory="ftpClientFactory">
                <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
                    <int:retry-advice />
                </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Java DSL - there's an example of the ftp inbound adapter in [the documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) - find `ftpInboundFlow` with your browser.

Or, you can [use annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans) - `@InboundChannel` adapter with a wired up [`FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ftp/inbound/FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java) with its dependencies.

On the outbound side, the DSL Ftp factory class has appropriate methods; for annotations, use `@ServiceActivator` on a [`FileTransferringMessageHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/handler/FileTransferringMessageHandler.java) `@Bean`.